# global .gitignore vs .gitignore in repository

Tags: git, github

If I have a global .gitignore setup and the project has .gitignore in repo does the one in the repo override the global one or does it add rules example:

If the global has:

```
*.exe
*.ini
```

and the repo has:

```
*.ini
*.co
```

will *.exe's get into the project?

Comment: For an actual answer to your question, see below, but I suggest that stuff like `*.exe` belong in project-specific `.gitignore` files. The global `.gitignore` is good if, for example, your text-editor leaves backup-files that other people don't care about.

Comment: this was only a example

Comment: Note: .gitignore is a convenience mechanism. You can still force gitignored file to get into project by using `git add --force`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both gitignores apply. So in this case, .exe would not get into the project.

However, if you had `!*.exe` in your local repository gitignore, .exe files would get into the repository.

GitHub has a good article about the subject: https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files

Answer (score 1):

Both `.gitignore` files apply. There is excellent documentation of how `.gitignore` files work in their man page. See `man gitignore` for more information.